# Flask blueprint structure: how to associate shared base.html to module-specific templates

Tags: flask

I have a flask app that I want to structure with blueprints. But I cannot figure out how to associate shared base.html to moduleA.html so moduleA.html can extend it. Could you please help me understand how I should do it or points me to the right resources? Thank you.

```
app/
   -- app.py
   -- modules/
      -- moduleA/
         -- templates/
            -- moduleA.html
         -- main.py
   -- static/
      -- templates/
         -- base.html


#### in moduleA.html ###
{% extends base.html %}

#### in base.html ###
<html>
</html>

#### in main.py ###
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

moduleA_bp = Blueprint('moduleA_bp', __name__,
                             template_folder="templates",
                             static_folder="static",
                             static_url_path="assets")

@moduleA_bp.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def view():
  return render_template('moduleA.html')

#### in app.py ###
from flask import Flask
from modules.moduleA.main import moduleA_bp

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(moduleA_bp, url_prefix="/moduleA")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Application Factories" to create your app and also move templates/ to the same level of your stactic/

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/appfactories/

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/layout/

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8D2bY.png)

Comment: Thank you. I will check it out!